# .NET Web API - JSON

Tags: c#, json, rest

I am writing a simple RESTful API that uses Json for both requests and responses.

Here is a sample method:

```
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetCourses", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public GetCoursesResponse GetCourses(GetCoursesRequest request)
    {
        var response = new GetCoursesResponse();
        var validationRequest = new SessionValidationRequest { AuthToken = request.AuthToken };

        try
        {
            // first, validate the session...
            var validationResponse = ValidateSession(validationRequest);

            if (validationResponse.Result == ServiceResultValue.Success)
            {
                response.Courses = CourseDAO.GetAll(ConnectionString());
                response.Result = ServiceResultValue.Success;
                response.ResultMessage = "";
            }

            return response;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.Result = ServiceResultValue.ServiceError;
            response.ResultMessage = "System error: " + ex.Message;
            return response;
        }
    }
```

When I view the operations page (by debugging the service and viewing the auto-generated help page) the information for the GetCourses methods shows the following for example response Json body:

```
{
    "NewAuthToken":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724",
    "Result":0,
    "ResultMessage":"String content",
    "Courses":[{
        "_x003C_Id_x003E_k__BackingField":2147483647,
        "action":0,
        "_x003C_Code_x003E_k__BackingField":"String content",
        "_x003C_Description_x003E_k__BackingField":"String content",
        "_x003C_Name_x003E_k__BackingField":"String content",
        "_x003C_StartDate_x003E_k__BackingField":"\/Date(928160400000-0300)\/"
    }]
}
```

If I make one simple change - that is change the name of the method from GetCourses to GetCourseList, rebuild and hit the operations page again, this time I get the following (correct) example Json:

```
{
    "NewAuthToken":"1627aea5-8e0a-4371-9022-9b504344e724",
    "Result":0,
    "ResultMessage":"String content",
    "Courses":[{
        "Action":2147483647,
        "Code":"String content",
        "Description":"String content",
        "Id":2147483647,
        "Name":"String content",
        "StartDate":"\/Date(928160400000-0300)\/"
    }]
}
```

A bit more background - the implementation of this web API has gone through some iterations and I *think* that the incorrect Json is an artifact of a previous error.  However, it almost seems that something has been cached and is referenced by method name - metadata somewhere - that is preserving the previous erroneous behavior.

I have recycled IIS, removed and recreated the application in IIS - all to no avail.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: Is your Courses class marked for serialization?

Comment: Yes.  As mentioned, the only change between the two scenarios is the name of the method.  The Course class is the same in both cases.